# Switch focus from panel or overlay to text of document from within plugin

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

In a `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` if the plugin is run using a key binding from within a panel or overlay is it possible for the plugin to switch focus from the overlay or panel to the text of the document?

Ideally if called from the overlay or find/replace panel then the overlay or panel would be closed when the focus changes to the text of the document, but if called from the console then the console would be left open.

I tried the following but it didn't work - I guess the `view` already has the focus so it changes nothing and an overlay or panel being displayed does not actually mean the view has lost focus.

```py
if self.view.settings().get('is_widget'):
    window = self.view.window()
    window.focus_view(window.active_view())
```

Thanks.